# Does anyone know how to use PIAsync?

Tags: python, selenium, vpn

I am trying to figure out how to use the PIASYNC lib for python. I have spent hours playing with it but I am seriously confused. How do I login to my account? How do I switch between the different countries? I can't find any examples and I am too much of a noob to figure out the lib by reading thru it. I don't know how to use this at all could anyone help out this noob? Just some examples or at least how I get started with it would be nice.

https://pypi.org/project/piasync/